# Reading cookies or sending info to Google Tag Manager

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

What is the correct way to send data to my Google Tag Manager?

I got a cookie notice that gives the user the opportunity to accept certain cookies (performance, marketing and analytics). So far I got this script to read the user' choice:

```
...
if (e.detail.performance) {
    setCookie('cookie_performance', e.detail.performance, 365);
}
if (e.detail.analytics) {
    setCookie('cookie_analytics', e.detail.analytics, 365);
}
if (e.detail.marketing) {
    setCookie('cookie_marketing', e.detail.marketing, 365);
}
...
```

However, this only sets a cookie in the user' browser. I like to know inside my Google Tag Manager container if the user accepted the cookie.

I have read stuff about using the `dataLayer`, but I am stuck on configuring the triggers or tags inside my container.

Is it possible to send an event to my container whenever the user accepts a certain cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If you go to the variables section and click "new" one choice for the variable type you have is "First Part Cookie".

As an aside, if the "365" in your code refers to the lifetime of your cookie in days (I assume it does, since 365 days is a year), be aware that on Safari and iOs Cookie lifetime will be limited to seven days due to the new version of their "[Intelligent Tracking Prevention](https://webkit.org/blog/8613/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-1/)".

While using cookies works fine for GTM, the datalayer usually is best practice (cookies come with a few caveats - the browser may not allow them, their size is limited, their number per domain is limited etc).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before there are inbuilt cookie variables for use within GTM, this way you can reference these in an if statement by using {{cookieVar_Name}} within GTM code.

However to answer your question about clueing in GTM about those cookies one way is to probably send along a dataLayer.push event with the necessary data.

For example you could adapt your current code to push an event when those cookies are set:

```
...
if (e.detail.performance) {
    setCookie('cookie_performance', e.detail.performance, 365);

window.dataLayer.push({
event: 'performanceEvent',
cookie_performance: true
});

}
if (e.detail.analytics) {
    setCookie('cookie_analytics', e.detail.analytics, 365);

window.dataLayer.push({
event: 'analyticsEvent',
cookie_analytics: true
});

}
if (e.detail.marketing) {
    setCookie('cookie_marketing', e.detail.marketing, 365);

window.dataLayer.push({
event: 'marketingEvent',
cookie_marketing: true
});

}
...
```

At this point you could create a custom event trigger named to say, marketingEvent, you could then use this trigger to fire a tag when that dataLayer.push is actioned/is consented to.

In regards to reading the cookies of returning customers, you could either use a customHTML tag with a cookie reading function:

```
//This function can be used to retrieve a cookie and its value by its key(name)

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

getCookie(cookie_marketing);
```

Or store the cookie value in an inbuilt GTM cookie variable and write an if statement:

```
if({{cookie_marketing}} == true){
// fire code here
}
```

Hope this helps get you on the right track.